# System date validate upon application launch

Tags: xcode, macos, date, applescript, system

I have built an applescript based app in Xcode V3.2.6 under OSX 10.6.7.
I want to have additional code to my application so when the system launched, it will compare the date I set in the application with the system date.
If date within range specified, proceed. If date check is out of range then terminate program immediately.

currently the code looks something like this:

---

```
on clicked the Object
    if name of theObject = "One" then
        try
            display dialog "ONE"
        end try

    else if name of theObject = "two" then
        try
            display dialog "TWO"
        end try
    end if
end clicked

on action theObject

end action
```

---

One of the very nice users in this fourm post Chuck has posted something. The code works great under apple scripter but not when I pasted into the Xcode.
Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong?

### posted by Chuck

```
set range to 3 * days 
set targetDate to (date "Saturday, March 19, 2011 12:00:00 AM") 
set currDate to current date 
if abs(targetDate - currDate) > range then 
    display dialog "quit" 
else 
    display dialog "continue" 
end if 

on abs(n) 
    if n < 0 then 
        return -n 
    else 
        return n 
    end if 
end abs
```

---

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you sure you pasted in the right sample code? The sample you provide is an action event handler, executed when the user clicks something in the interface, and doesn't appear to do anything regarding the current date. If you want code to execute when the application launches, I think you need to place it in the `launch` event for the application (it's been a while since I wrote an AppleScript application with Xcode).

Comment: Hello Chuck, yeah I am trying to have it check for system dates so if it expires it won't even allow user to click on the interface, it will display a message and terminates the program. I am a beginner at Xcode and interface builder, would you kindly point me to the right direction on where the launch event would be? and thank you very much for your reply and edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I worked with the technology formerly known as AppleScript Studio. :) However, I just created a Cocoa-AppleScript application and I see that the file `UntitledAppDelegate.applescript` has the following by default:

```
script UntitledAppDelegate
    property parent : class "NSObject"

    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
        -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
        -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
        return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_

end script
```

Note the `on applicationWillFinishLaunching_` handler and the comment placed there by Xcode. This is where you want to place code that will execute when the program launches. For example, I placed a `beep` statement in there and the application beeped when it launched. So I'm guessing you could have something like this:

```
on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened
    set range to 3 * days 
    set targetDate to (date "Saturday, March 19, 2011 12:00:00 AM") 
    set currDate to current date 
    if (currDate - targetDate) > range then 
        display dialog "quit" 
    else 
        display dialog "continue" 
    end if 
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_
```

Comment: when I add in your code to a blank test try it worked great, but can you please instruct me where should I insert my part of the code?

Comment: so what I tried to do is:
with a simple button in the interface builder, I can't succesfully compile. It gives me an error.

Comment: script UntitledAppDelegate 
    property parent : class "NSObject" 
 
    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification) 
        -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
(YOUR CODE) 
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_ 
 
    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender) 
        -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits  
        return current application's NSTerminateNow 
    end applicationShouldTerminate_ 
 
end script 

on clicked theObjected
 display dialog “test”
end clicked theObjected

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm unable to be of any further help. It's been years since I worked with AppleScript Studio (Apple's former name for this technology), and I'm unfamiliar with the newer version. You might try the forums at macscripter.net if no one else here is able to help out: http://macscripter.net/viewforum.php?id=3.

Comment: sounds good, I'll see what I can find out myself!  Thanks very much for all your help, Chuck!! :) take care.